# Angular Lazy Loading - Loading a module gives 404, using Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, angular, iis, visual-studio-2017

I have created an empty Angular project in Visual Studio as a web project. Then I tried to follow a guide([this](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/modules/lazy-loading-module.html)), how to lazy load a module. But it doesn't work, it gives 404 error, for some reasons './' relative paths do not work:

[image: 2]]

Packages:

[image: 3]]

Structure:

[image: 4]]

[image: 15]]

Files:

[image: 5]]

[image: 6]]

[image: 7]]

[image: 8]]

[image: 9]]

[image: 10]]

[image: 11]]

[image: 12]]

[image: 13]]

[image: 14]]

Comment: In structure image, `lazy.module.ts` file is missing. It should be inside app/lazy folder.

Comment: I made the screenshot before I added that file. I will edit the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use LazyModule in app.routing.ts like this-

```
{ path: 'lazy', loadChildren: 'app/lazy/lazy.module#LazyModule' }
```

instead of

```
{ path: 'lazy', loadChildren: 'lazy/lazy.module#LazyModule' }
```

Refer this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/vpCqRHDAj7V6mlN1AknN?p=preview)

Comment: Do you know why this behaviour and why in tutorial worked? It solved my issue, but I want to know more details. Thank you.

Comment: There may be a typo in tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your loadChildren path in your app.routing.ts into :

```
{ path: 'lazy', loadchildren: './lazy/lazy.module#Lazymodule }
```

Comment: It does not work.